# How to prevent a new empty VSCode instance from opening after closing a remote WSL connection

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vscode-remote, wsl-2

I use VSCode with [Remote WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) extension.

When I quit remote WSL I use the `Close Remote Connection` button/command. VSCode closes the current window, but automatically opens a new empty instance.

How to prevent a new empty VSCode instance from opening after closing a remote WSL connection?

90% of the time when I finish WSL I don't need a new VSCode window.

*Note: I can use `X` of course, but I'm not sure this is the right way to leave a remote connection*

Answer (score 1):

I can understand your concern around terminating the whole thing (`X`), but I don't think it's a problem here (and is the right way to accomplish what you want).  When VSCode exits, the WSL2 subsystem (and instance) is still running in the background.

You can demonstrate this by running `wsl.exe -l -v` from cmd or PowerShell and seeing that it is still in the `Running` state after exiting VSCode.

To truly exit the WSL instance, you would need to run `wsl.exe -t <distro>` or, to shut down the entire subsystem, `wsl.exe --shutdown`.  I'm going to assume that those are "clean" shutdowns, but at any rate, we know that VSCode's termination is "clean" since it really only terminates its own WSL processes when it exits.

You can further demonstrate this by:

1. Opening a WSL shell outside of VSCode
2. Running `ps auxw`
3. Opening VSCode with a WSL remote connection
4. Running `ps aux` in the original shell again (notice the VSCode processes)
5. Close VSCode
6. Running `ps aux` one final time in the original shell to see that only the VSCode processes have been terminated.